# How do I change my grid so that it counts left to right, top to bottom?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I am trying to create a square grid of map coordinates with a `gridOrder` count that starts counting in the top left corner, left to right, top to bottom.

When the coordinates are shown on a map the `gridOrder` count should look like this (desired correct version):

```
 1 | 2 | 3
---+---+---
 4 | 5 | 6
---+---+---
 7 | 8 | 9
```

But currently it looks like this (current wrong version):

```
 3 | 6 | 9
---+---+---
 2 | 5 | 8
---+---+---
 1 | 4 | 7
```

How can I adjust the code below to assign a `gridOrder` count in my desired pattern of left to right, top to bottom?

I know the problem is with how I assign `gridOrder` during the `map()`. But I have tried many different variations and I can't get it to work.

```TypeScript
import bbox from "@turf/bbox";
import { Units, point } from "@turf/helpers";
import pointGrid from "@turf/point-grid";
import buffer from "@turf/buffer";

const createGridCoordinates = (
  centerCoordinates: google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  numPointsPerSide: number,
  gridDimension: number,
  unitOfMeasure: Units
) => {
  // Calculate the cell size
  const cellSize = gridDimension / (numPointsPerSide - 1);

  // Calculate half the grid size to find the distance from center to edges of bounding box
  const halfGridSize = gridDimension / 2;

  // Make the bounding box around a center point and a circle buffer radius
  // Radius is extended by 10% of a cellSize (cellSize / 10) to include
  // east and north edges when gridDimension is an exact multiple of the grid spacing
  const boundingBox = bbox(
    buffer(
      point([centerCoordinates.lng, centerCoordinates.lat]),
      halfGridSize + cellSize / 10,
      {
        units: unitOfMeasure,
      }
    )
  );

  // Make the grid. This is an array of grid coordinates.
  const grid = pointGrid(boundingBox, cellSize, {
    units: unitOfMeasure,
  });

  // Extract the coordinates from the grid and add gridOrder
  const coordinatesGrid = grid.features.map((feature, index) => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    const coordinatesGridItem = {
      coordinates: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
      gridOrder: index + 1,
    };
    return coordinatesGridItem;
  });

  return coordinatesGrid;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Instead of trying to change the value of `gridOrder` in strange ways, I just sorted the grid coordinates before assigning `gridOrder`.

Here is the full working code:

```TypeScript
const createGridCoordinates = (
  centerCoordinates: google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  numPointsPerSide: number,
  gridDimension: number,
  unitOfMeasure: Units
) => {
  // Calculate the cell size
  const cellSize = gridDimension / (numPointsPerSide - 1);

  // Calculate half the grid size to find the distance from center to edges of bounding box
  const halfGridSize = gridDimension / 2;

  // Make the bounding box around a center point and a circle buffer radius
  // Radius is extended by 10% of a cellSize (cellSize / 10) to include
  // east and north edges when gridDimension is an exact multiple of the grid spacing
  const boundingBox = bbox(
    buffer(
      point([centerCoordinates.lng, centerCoordinates.lat]),
      halfGridSize + cellSize / 10,
      {
        units: unitOfMeasure,
      }
    )
  );

  // Make the grid
  const grid = pointGrid(boundingBox, cellSize, {
    units: unitOfMeasure,
  });

  // Make a normal array of the grid coordinates
  const coordinates = grid.features.map((feature) => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    const coordinatesGridItem = {
      coordinates: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    };
    return coordinatesGridItem;
  });

  // Sort by latitude (y) in descending order, then by longitude (x) in ascending order
  coordinates.sort((a, b) => {
    const coord1 = a.coordinates;
    const coord2 = b.coordinates;

    if (coord1.lat > coord2.lat) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (coord1.lat < coord2.lat) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (coord1.lng < coord2.lng) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (coord1.lng > coord2.lng) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  // Add gridOrder to the new array
  const coordinatesGrid = coordinates.map((coordinate, index) => {
    const coordinatesGridItem = {
      ...coordinate,
      gridOrder: index + 1,
    };
    return coordinatesGridItem;
  });

  return coordinatesGrid;
};
```